# Why Should't We Create a meta for open discussion?

Tags: discussion

Some fans would love to share their crazy fantasy. A Special dedicated page would allow them to share their version of their favorite anime. This page should only allow for spoiler, threads and open discussion.

Comment: if you want a place for discussion about anime that will be [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-)

Comment: This is what the chat is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Meta is about *discussion about the site itself*, it doesn't directly have anything to do with anime or manga, and while open discussions are often allowed in meta, we must remain on topic.

If you want, you can always come to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-), we make crazy discussions like those all the time.